# директива не видит значение, переданное в контроллер из вида, при загрузке страницы

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-directive

При загрузке страницы `ctrl.customClass` имеет значение `'undefined'`. При активации директивы через ng-click  `ctrl.customClass` принимает переданное значение css класса, но оно не инициируется в `ng-class`, т.е. стиль не задействуется.
В чем может быть причина того, что контроллер директивы не видит значение, передданое из вида при загрузке?

Вот упрощенный пример:

JS:

```
    app.directive("myDirective", function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: {
          header: '=',
          customClass: '@?'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
          var ctrl = this;
          var test = ctrl.customClass;
          /*some code*/
        }],
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "myDirective.html"
      }
    });
```

CSS:

```
.title-color-red {
  color: red;
}

.title-color-green {
  color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <my-directive header="First block" custom-class="title-color-red">
   <div>Some data</div>
 </my-directive>
 <my-directive header="Second block" custom-class="title-color-green">
   <div>Other data</div>
 </my-directive>    


<script type="text/ng-template" id="myDirective.html">
  <div ng-class="ctrl.customClass">{{ctrl.header}}</div>
  <div ng-transclude></span>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Приведенный код рабочий, за исключением неверного использования `header`.

В настрояках директивы он указан как `=`, это значит, что значение должно быть выражением ангуляра, которое вычисляется.

В данном примере происходит исключение при попытке разобрать **выражение** `First block` и `Second block` поэтому ничего не выводится, если заменить их на строки, то все заработает:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: {
      header: '=',
      customClass: '@?'
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      var ctrl = this;
      var test = ctrl.customClass; /*some code*/
    }],
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: "myDirective.html"
  }
});
```

```css
.title-color-red {
  color: red;
}

.title-color-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <my-directive header="'First block'" custom-class="title-color-red">
    <div>Some data</div>
  </my-directive>
  <my-directive header="'Second block'" custom-class="title-color-green">
    <div>Other data</div>
  </my-directive>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myDirective.html">
    <div ng-class="ctrl.customClass">{{ctrl.header}}</div>
    <div ng-transclude>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Либо вместо `=` нужно использовать `@`, тогда значением поля будет строка из атрибута

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: {
      header: '@',
      customClass: '@?'
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      var ctrl = this;
      var test = ctrl.customClass; /*some code*/
    }],
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: "myDirective.html"
  }
});
```

```css
.title-color-red {
  color: red;
}

.title-color-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <my-directive header="First block" custom-class="title-color-red">
    <div>Some data</div>
  </my-directive>
  <my-directive header="Second block" custom-class="title-color-green">
    <div>Other data</div>
  </my-directive>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myDirective.html">
    <div ng-class="ctrl.customClass">{{ctrl.header}}</div>
    <div ng-transclude>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! В header ошибка да, но код я написала на скорую руку как пример использования передачи класса `css`, у меня проблемма именно в нем: то есть по всей логике класс из вида должен передаваться в директиву, так, как это работает в примере, но этого не проиходит.

Comment: @JaneDoe, как видно в примере: код полностью рабочий. Без [mcve] нельзя сказать почему именно в твоем случае не работает.

Comment: @JaneDoe, попробуй добавить пример, в котором твоя ошибка будет воспроизводиться